# Grand Totals with Rollup

Tags: sql, t-sql

Have a query for totals by county and quarter. Trying to add a grand total at bottom for all counties with quarterly totals for all counties as well.

Added the code for rollup but its not returning anything, table is same with no grand total

```
select  isnull(convert(VARCHAR,DCOUNTYNAME),'GRAND TOTAL') AS  County, 
    Year(DDATE) as Year, ---selects year value for total and quarter totals
    count(*) as Total, ---counts year totals
    sum(case when DATEPART(q, DDATE)=1 then 1 else 0 end) as Q1,
    sum(case when DATEPART(q, DDATE)=2 then 1 else 0 end) as Q2,
    sum(case when DATEPART(q, DDATE)=3 then 1 else 0 end) as Q3,
    sum(case when DATEPART(q, DDATE)=4 then 1 else 0 end) as Q4
into #tfinal
from Cert
where FLAG = 'o' and year(cast(ddDate as date)) ='2013' 
group by DCOUNTYNAME,
         Year(DDATE) with rollup
```

results now

```
County      Year    Total   Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
IMPERIAL    2013    129 5   20  100 4
FRESNO      2013    67  19  16  15  17
SAN DIEGO   2013    408 70  66  94  194
```

results desired to get

```
County      Year    Total   Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
IMPERIAL    2013    129 5   20  100 4
FRESNO      2013    67  19  16  15  17
SAN DIEGO   2013    408 70  66  94  194
Grand Total         595 94 106 209  215
```

Comment: Try removing `into #tfinal` and see it it comes up.

Comment: @Mihai: Why should it behave different then?

Comment: I tried something very similar in my DB and it worked for me. 
Maybe we can help if you would provide a schema with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: @NePh I was thinking ROLLUP might return NULL so it might conflict with his table.

Comment: @Mihai: Since the temp table is created along with the `SELECT ... INTO` I don´t think it can conflict with it.

Comment: I took out the Into #tfinal and still no totals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like, based on the comments, you may have achieved the results you were looking for already. Here's another way, and this method allows you to explicitly control how the totals are displayed.

```
With CTE as (
--Insert Existing query without rollup here
)

Select * From CTE

Union All

Select 'Grand Total' as County
    , null as Year
    , SUM(Total) as Total
    , SUM(Q1) as Q1
    , SUM(Q2) as Q2
    , SUM(Q3) as Q3
    , SUM(Q4) as Q4

From CTE
```